# react-dates solution to select single date from calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dates

I am trying to highlight the selected date on click of specific date using React-dates but didn't get any solution for it. 
I had used:

```
isDayHighlighted={day1 => returnDates().some(day2 => isSameDay(day1, day2))}
```

which works correctly to highlight dates. but for specific date how can i do this.

Comment: what do you mean? selected date is highlighted by default

Comment: oh really? In my case it is highlighted only on hover.

Comment: you can see it in their [examples docs](http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=DateRangePicker%20%28DRP%29&selectedStory=default&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel)

Comment: I had used the SingleDatePicker component of react-dates

Comment: same behavior, the only difference is that it is auto close after the selection (which you can control)

Comment: Thanks for your help it works. somehow i am able to show selected date highlighted. but now once i select the date it is always showing selected even after clicking on next previous arrow of calendar. is there any way on-clicking outside the selected date can be deselected.

Comment: you mean reset the selected date when navigating to different months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly (based on your comments), you want to reset the selected date whenever the current displayed month is changed.

You can hook to `onNextMonthClick` and `onPrevMonthClick` and set the date to `null`.

[Running example](https://codesandbox.io/s/oj612kpxvy)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { date: null, focused: false };

  onDateChange = date => {
    this.setState({ date });
  };

  onFocusChange = ({ focused }) => {
    this.setState({ focused });
  };

  resetDate = () => {
    this.setState({ date: null });
  };

  render() {
    const { focused, date } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>React Dates Test</h1>
        <SingleDatePicker
          date={date}
          focused={focused}
          numberOfMonths={1}
          onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
          onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
          onNextMonthClick={this.resetDate}
          onPrevMonthClick={this.resetDate}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a-lot buddy. It is really helpful.

Comment: @user10584677 no problem. was it answered your question?